# Video and audio scrolling not work when using HTML5 audio on a webpage

Tags: ubuntu-one

Upload any webm or theora video or ogg audio.
Then try to play them with browser or embed into web page using html5 < video > or < audio > tags.

Playback scrolling does not work.

Answer (score 2):

If by "scrolling" you mean "seeking", then I believe the issue is that the current Ubuntu One file server doesn't support HTTP Range requests, which is needed to seek when playing HTML5 video or audio.

Comment: Yes, I mean seeking. I checked out if server supports Content-Range. Started download a file with the wget and aborted it. Then continued downloading with -c -S keys, it continued to download and returned head Content-Range: bytes 1908203-23877827/23877828 So, Content-Range is supported.